# Importing config.py inside __init__.py from different directory

Tags: python, python-import, configuration-files

```
dir1\
    __init__.py
    config.py

dir2\
    __init__.py
    module1.py
```

In order to protect sensitive config settings, I have a file `config.py` in let's say `dir1`. I have `dir2` that has the main Python files.

I want all the modules in `dir2` to be able to access `config.py`. So I thought to import it once inside `__init__.py` that is inside `dir2`.

How do I do this? I tried putting this inside `__init__.py` in `dir2`:

```
# __init__.py in dir2

import os
import sys

config_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['userprofile'],'Path','To','dir1')
sys.path.append(config_dir)

from dir1 import config
```

I put this in `module1.py`

```
# module1.py
from config import USERS
```

but when I run `module1` I get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`.

Comment: Does config.py define an object? Also have you tried doing it with config.py in the same directory?

Comment: `config.py` only has `lists` and `dicts`, such as `USERS`

Answer (score 0):

The directory with the import needs a `__init__.py` file even if it's empty. This is so the Python Interpreter can recognise that it is a module and is therefore importable.

Comment: It has one. Forgot to put that in the question, will edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer:

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

I think you already found the solution, you just have to put the code that you placed in `dir2/__init__.py` in `module1.py` and every other module in which you want to use files from dir1.

As far as I understand, the `__init__.py` file is just for python to recognize the folder, but not for actual initialization code for a project.